# Do I need the left table indexed for efficiency when left merging with another indexed DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, indexing

I want to do a *left* [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16/generated/pandas.merge.html) to join two pandas DataFrame:

```
merged_df = left_df.merge(right_df, how='left', left_on='id', right_index=True)
```

`left_df` is not indexed, it only has an `id`, but `right_df` **is** indexed. 
I have not indexed `left_df` since it changes continuously, but **for the merge would it be faster if the left DataFrame is also indexed?** In my case the merge is done very frequently and until now the left DataFrames has up to 60k rows and the right up to 1000.

I have not checked pandas' [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16/generated/pandas.merge.html) code, but since in the left merge it keeps all rows of the left DataFrame I am not sure if indexing it would increase this merge's speed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just test it with fake data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# df1: 60k rows, not indexed
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': np.random.randint(0, 100, 60_000),
                           'b': np.random.randint(0, 100, 60_000)})
# df2: 1k rows, indexed
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'c': np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)},
                   index =  np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000))
```

**Joins Performances**

```
%timeit pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='a', right_index=True, how='left')
55.4 ms ± 6.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pd.merge(df1.set_index('a'), df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, 
how='left')
49.8 ms ± 3.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This already shows a better performance when joining on index. However I am also setting the index in the join, which just need to be done once if you have multiple joins. Let's see time split between the two operations:

```
%time df1.set_index('a', inplace=True)
Wall time: 936 µs

%timeit pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
48 ms ± 3.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```